# not able to install app on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, provisioning-profile, ipa, ios-provisioning

I had build an app using xcode 4.6 and base sdk as 6.0

This app is in-house app where I used to send updated provision file after adding UDID.

The client sent me iPhone 5s UDID and I sent him updated provision file.

When he tries to install, it shows app with name. When he click on that app, it says "Installing" and lasts forever.

Any idea why this is happening?

Even I tried this, but still same issue.

Any idea why this happening?

[image]

---

**I am able to install on my iPhone 4s/ iOS 7... the problem is with iPhone 5s/ios7**

For installing app, below are steps we follow.

1. I send updated provision file to client based on UDID they send me.
2. Client drag provision file to iTune
3. Client drag the iPA file to iTunes App
4. Client drag the app from iTunes>>App to respective iPhone...

that's it...

This process is working with my iPhone 4s/ iOS 7.

But the problem is faced with only iPhone 5s.

---

Just now when I tries to add the updated provision file in my xcode, it says "Valid signing identity not found". But it still install app on my iPhone?? I am really confused...

Any idea what is going on?

This is really making me crazy.

Comment: are you able to instal in simulator or using any 3rd party libraries?

Comment: @Radu : I am able to install on my iPhone 4s/ iOS 7... the problem is with iPhone 5s/ios7

Comment: there might be a gap in the architectures but i'm not sure is the app setting set for arm7 and  arm7s?

Answer (score 3):

I've the same problem and my error was because I was archiving to wrong provisioning profile!
You should select the same provisioning profile that's included in your target project under code signing -> provisioning profile.

I was archiving for the iOS Team provisioning profile development and not the one attached with my app ID in apple developer center (and this one also should be the one that included in your project target under code signing)

Happy coding
:)

Comment: not sure... Client agreed to have app on the store so I didnt looked into this issue... but your point might be the reason for me..

Answer (score 2):

There might be a gap in the architectures but i'm not sure is the app setting set for arm7 and arm7s.
Keep in mind iPhone 5s is on 64 bits follow this [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html) to update you project settings

Comment: The OS can install and run 32-bit software. Also, this has nothing to do with how the project was built. Install is failing/stuck, not running the binary.

Comment: The os can install 32-bit software on a 64 -bit device really? it is easy enough to test send a ipa build and install it directly to the iPhone 5s with iTunes is it doesn't install you have a settings problem my friend

Comment: @Radu Yes, it can. The system contains 32-bit and 64-bit frameworks and can dynamically link the correct one according to the binary type.

Answer (score 1):

How is your client installing? We've seen that some web servers seem to cause install problems with iOS. He should first try to install the IPA file through iTunes or iPhone Configuration Utility and see if that works. If it does, try switching to a different web server for hosting the IPA file.

If this does not help, have him connect his phone to a Mac and take a look at the console output, if SpringBoard throws any errors that may shed light on why install stalls.

Comment: Client and myself also tried through iTunes... add provision file to iTunes... then drag iPA files to iTunes App... then drag app from iTunes to respective iPhone... done...

Comment: You have to connect his device to Console.app and see what the output is.

Comment: @FahimParkar You have to connect the client's phone (the one that doesn't work) to Console and see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct UDID for him? How did he obtain it? If he got his UDID using one of the many apps on the App Store, they no longer give the correct UDID on iOS 7+. You'll find the last bunch of digits will all be FFFFFF

Comment: Are you actually signing the app with the provisioning profile that has his UDID? I strongly recommend http://testflightapp.com for AdHoc distribution as it takes all the hassles away and it's simple for people to register their devices.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the very same issue. But I just got it installed on iphone 5 and 5s both.

Here's what i did:

1. With my testfligtapp account, invited people to beta testing
2. Added udid on dev account on apple.
3. Once the device is added, went to iOS provisioning profiles. Selected one of the profiles. Double clicked to edit that profile. Selected ALL devices by putting check on all. (This included a 5S as well) Saved and downloaded the provisioning profile.
4. On testflightapp, went to apps - double clicked on the build - update profile (uploaded the new profile, as downloaded from apple account)

Verified the apps are now accessible thru testflightapp.com on both 5 and 5S.